# Swiper - Unable to disable touch on mobile

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

As I stated [here](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/3318), I'm having trouble in disabling gestures totally on lower resolutions.
By using `breakpoints` in conjunction with as said "dedicated API touch options" such as `touchRatio, shortSwipes/longSwipes, allowTouchMove, allowSlidePrev/next` don't produce the expected results. This is the current implementation:

```
swiperProject = new Swiper('.headline__container', {
    direction: 'vertical',
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 500,
    lazy: true,
    preloadImages: false,
    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
      clickable: true,
    },
    breakpoints: {
      320: {
       // I tried with allowTouchMove: false, allowSlidePrev/next: false too, but nothing
        touchRatio: 0,
        shortSwipes: false,
        longSwipes: false
      },
      992: {
        touchRatio: 1,
        shortSwipes: true,
        longSwipes: true
      }
    }
  });
```

Basically, my goal is to deactivate gestures on mobile in order to prevent the scrolling blocking of the `body` itself - these slides are currently set on vertical mode.

Anyone know how to achieve this? I read the above tries on other questions, but they don't helped me.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I forced `pointer-events: none` on mobile. Hope in the next future the team will fix these API options soon.

Thanks everyone for the attention.